# crontab php script that execute graph and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, logging, graph

i need help for the following question since i cannot figure out why this happens.
I have a RHEL in which is crontab a PHP script that run every 5 min.

```
05,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/MYSCRIPT.php
00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/MYSCRIPT.php
```

The script:
1-collect the infos stored in the MySQL
2-Through graph api, collect the inbox mail (on O365)
3-perform some checks

The concept of mail receipt is a sort of 'heartbeat' from a system, so every 1 hour the systems sends a mail and i need only to check the if it is arrived.
The check (point 3) consists on: if the mail arrived no later than 1 1/2 hours since the last email all is fine, otherwise it send an alert like 'the system XXX appears to be down'.
Since many active systems (that send the heartbeat) once or twice a day are deliberately disabled, i added to the mysql table a downtime field, that is actually a json string. Example:
(1- monday - 7 sunday)

```
{
    "1":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "2":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "3":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "4":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "5":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "6":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},
    "7":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]}
}
```

in the code there's a function that check if the mail arrived in a downtime range or not:
param: downtime calendar, now (datetime), null (the third param is usually null)

```
function is_downtime($cal,$now,$getKey=null){
    $dayofweek = $now->format("N");
    $to_ret=array();
    $hournowint = intval($now->format("His"));
    if(array_key_exists($dayofweek, $cal)){
        foreach ($cal[$dayofweek] as $key => $value) {
            $inthour1 = intval(str_replace(":", "", trim($value[0])));
            $inthour2 = intval(str_replace(":", "", trim($value[1])));
            if(isBetween($value[0],$value[1],$now->format("H:i:s"))){
                if($getKey){return [true,$dayofweek,$key];}
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if($getKey){return [false,-1,-1];}
    return false;
}
```

and the function isBetween:

```
function isBetween($from, $till, $input) {
    $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i:s', $from);
    $t = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i:s', $till);
    $i = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i:s', $input);
    if ($f > $t) $t->modify('+1 day');
    return ($f <= $i && $i <= $t) || ($f <= $i->modify('+1 day') && $i <= $t);
}
```

I can assure you this works fine. Every 5 min this function is called through this invocation:

```
...
if(is_downtime(json_decode($conf["down_calendar"],true),$dtnow)){
  //do stuff
}else{
  //do other stuff
}
...
```

but sometimes, when i pass a calendar and a datetime that obviously is not i a downtime range, it enter anyway a true case.
Example:

$dtnow is obviously a clear new datetime, the calendar is as prevously

```
$dtnow=new Datetime();
$calendar='{"1":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"2":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"3":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"4":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"5":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"6":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]},"7":{"0":["06:50:00","07:10:00"]}}'
```

If i pass this parameter to the "isDowntime" function and now = friday 16:33, the function says it is true (obvioulsy wrong).
To have an evidence i added some log code that write into a file:

```
$log->write("DBG - conf=".json_encode($conf));
$log->write("DBG - dtnow=".$dtnow->format("YmdHis"));
if(is_downtime(json_decode($conf["down_calendar"],true),$dtnow)){
  $log->write("II - CNT - configuration XX/YY is in downtime");
  //do stuff
}else{
  //do other stuff
}
```

The Log shows:

```
17/02/23 16:35:04 : DBG - conf={ ..., "down_calendar":"{\"1\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"2\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"3\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"4\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"5\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"6\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]},\"7\":{\"0\":[\"06:50:00\",\"07:10:00\"]}}", ...}
17/02/23 16:35:04 : DBG - dtnow=20230217163500
17/02/23 16:35:04 : II - CNT - configuration XX/YY is in downtime
```

The fact is that if execute the function with the same parameter 100 times after the problem appears, the function correctly return "false".
This problem is not recurrent, for example, every Friday at 16:35, so it is difficult to debug.

How is it possible?
Can you help me, not to resolve, but at least to understand how can i debug better the problem.

thank you in advance.

```
...
if(is_downtime(json_decode($conf["down_calendar"],true),$dtnow)){
  //do stuff
}else{
  //do other stuff
}
...
```

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `*/5 * * * *` will check every 5 minutes

Comment: i know...  but i prefer this way, not only for me, because sometimes other user read the crontab :D

Answer (score 0):

This is very poorly written PHP code.

For instance the variables `$to_ret`, `$hournowint`, `$inthour1` and `$inthour2` are defined but never used. This makes me suspect that the code is not stable. That's just one of the problems.

The code is difficult to read and contains conversions that are not needed. Remember that a simple `"06:00:00" > "05:00:00"` will also work correctly.

I don't see anything obvious wrong that could explain your problem, but bugs, like the one you're experiencing, often hide in code that is difficult to understand.

I would propose a complete rewrite.

How about:

```php
function isTimeInPeriod($time, $period)
{
    [$start, $finish] = $period;
    if ($start > $finish) {
        return ($time >= $start) || ($time <= $finish);
    } else {
        return ($time >= $start) && ($time <= $finish);
    }
}

function system_is_down($downtimeCalender, $datetime, $verbose = false){
    $time      = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
    $dayofweek = $datetime->format("N");
    if (array_key_exists($dayofweek, $downtimeCalender)) {
        foreach ($downtimeCalender[$dayofweek] as $periodNo => $period) {
            if (isTimeInPeriod($time, $period)) {
                return $verbose ? [true, $dayofweek, $periodNo] : true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $verbose ? [false, -1, -1] : false;
}
```

I kept the code more-or-less compatible with yours, but simplified it where possible. Simpler code means that it is easier to understand, and bugs have fewer places to hide.

This code is untested, so if you want to use it you'll have to test it yourself first.

Does this solve your problem? I have my doubts. It could, but I have a suspicion that your gremlin is hiding somewhere else.

Isn't there a more direct way to see if a system is online than using emails?

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly no.. i cannot check through another way. i really appreciate your help... i'll try with your code.. indeed, "Simpler code means that it is easier to understand, and bugs have fewer places to hide." as you wrote. Thank you